# How to make Repeater fall particles?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Whan you fall in Minecraft, particles appear underneath you. But when you fall on a not-full block, for example a Repeater, you get the particles of the block underneath:

[image: The super ultimate unbelivable grass particles in the middle of a repeater thing full of the new fall particles. Now we have to find out how to make Minecraft show us their super duper one-in-a-million hero Repeater fall particles. Consider using a super mega awesome superglitch.]

**How do I get to have Repeater particles?**  Is there any bug making repeater fall particles possible? **It seems to me that the fall particles are made from the block texture, not premade, so you could somehow get little parts of repeater textures flying around you.**

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here. Do you want to have repeater particles when jumping onto a repeater?

Comment: @MrLemon That's exactly what he's asking. He wants repeater (stone) particles when he jumps onto a repeater instead of the block below it (in this case, dirt from grass).

Comment: As far as I know, repeaters don't have a particle associated with them, as they are not a solid block.

Comment: What are you exactly trying to achieve consequently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, repeater fall particles are impossible to create by directly falling onto it. However, you can create them by placing a block at the side if the repeater and jumping/falling from a specific height exactly on the side of the block.  Here is a picture of when you do it right:
[image: Falling]

There are no stone blocks underneath the repeater block and as you can notice because of the red lines in the particles. I'm not directly standing on the repeater because I landed on the side of the full block.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's such thing in Vanilla Minecraft, however you could have [custom resource pack](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Creating_a_resource_pack#Packaging_Resource_Packs_with_your_Maps), which texture of any block(stone block for example) replaced with repeater texture and [automatically place](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lH1sCNWxikA) that(stone) block under the repeater whenever it is placed.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the particles are the same, whether you land on a repeater or not. (i.e. there is no such thing as "repeater particles").

I think you either took the photos at different times, when the particles didn't have enough time to spread out, or you fell from a different height.

Anyone, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @RudolfJelínek Sorry, your question was unclear to me, atleast

Comment: @RudolfJelínek repeaters may not have a particle associated with them.

Comment: @RudolfJelínek you may need to use redstone particles.